# Usando REGEX em PHP para capturar qualquer número que não esteja dentro de aspas simples

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

Tenho estudado regex há algum tempo e me deparo agora com um problema: capturar todos os números, inclusive decimais, **que não estejam dentro de aspas simples**.

Estou criando uma espécie de *viewer* para códigos PHP a fim de aprender a utilizar melhor as regex. Tenho a seguinte regex funcionando, ela retorna pra mim todos os números decimais de uma dada string:

```
preg_match_all('/(\d+\.\d+)/', $text, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);
```

O que eu gostaria é de retornar não somente os decimais, mas todos os caracteres numéricos **que não estejam dentro de aspas simples**. Alguma ideia de como eu poderia fazer isso? Agradeço qualquer iluminação, pois estou totalmente no escuro, já tentei diversas combinações de regex e nenhuma deu certo. Realizo os meus testes sempre no [regex101.com](https://regex101.com).

OBS: eu consigo retornar todos os caracteres numéricos **DENTRO** das aspas e não somente os que estiverem de fora delas:

```
preg_match_all('/(\'(\d+)\')/', $text, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Embora seja possível fazer uma regex - [possivelmente bem complicada](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-best-trick.html#simplecase) - envolvendo [*lookaheads* e *lookbehinds*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), acho mais fácil usar um pequeno "truque" que se utiliza de [grupos de captura](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html).

Basicamente, se você tem uma string como esta:

```
$texto = "123 abc '456' def789'112' ghi";
```

Pelo que entendi, você só quer capturar `123` e `789`, pois são os números que não estão entre aspas simples (`'`). Então você poderia ter uma expressão assim:

```
preg_match_all("/\'\\d+\'|(\\d+)/", $texto, $matches);
```

Esta regex usa [alternância](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) (`|`) para dizer que quer uma coisa **ou** outra. Essas "coisas" são:

1. número entre aspas simples: `'\d+'`, **ou**
2. número (sem as aspas) e dentro de parênteses, para formar um grupo de captura: `(\d+)`

*Lembrando que alguns caracteres da regex estão devidamente escapados com `\` por estarem dentro de uma string.*

Com isso, um *match* da regex pode cair em um dos 2 casos:

- se o número estiver entre aspas simples, cai no primeiro trecho
- senão, cai no segundo trecho

Se cai no primeiro caso, o grupo de captura não é preenchido, e se cai no segundo trecho, o grupo de captura é preenchido.

Portanto, para pegar os números que não estão entre aspas simples, basta verificar se o grupo de captura está preenchido. E para que o array retorne em um formato mais fácil de verificar isso, podemos usar a opção `PREG_SET_ORDER`:

```
$texto = "123 abc '456' def789'112' ghi";
preg_match_all("/\'\\d+\'|(\\d+)/", $texto, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);
var_dump($matches);
```

Este código produz a seguinte saída:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(3) "123"
    [1]=>
    string(3) "123"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(5) "'456'"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(3) "789"
    [1]=>
    string(3) "789"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(5) "'112'"
  }
}
```

Repare que, nos *matches* que caem no segundo caso (número não está entre aspas simples), o array possui 2 posições. A primeira corresponde a todo o *match*, e a segunda corresponde ao grupo de captura (neste caso são iguais, mas dependendo da expressão, pode não ser).

Já nos casos em que o número está entre aspas, o respectivo array só possui uma posição, pois nestes casos o grupo de captura não é preenchido.

Então basta percorrer o array de *matches* e verificar quais dos arrays internos possui o grupo de captura setado (ou seja, é só ver se o tamanho é maior que 1):

```
foreach ($matches as $m) {
    if (count($m) > 1) { // grupo de captura preenchido (número não está entre aspas)
        echo $m[1]. "\n";
    }
}
```

A saída deste `foreach` é:

```
123
789
```

---

Se quiser números com casas decimais, basta trocar `\d+` por `\d+\.\d+` (que dentro da string ficaria `\\d+\\.\\d+`) ou qualquer outra expressão que estiver usando para capturar os números.

Se as casas depois da vírgula forem opcionais, por exemplo, pode usar `\d+(?:\.\d+)?`. Não é o foco específico da pergunta, mas a validação de números pode se tornar complicada, [pois tudo depende de quais casos você quer considerar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4247184).

---

Como lembrado pelo [@fernandosavio](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/6333/fernandosavio) nos [comentários](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/352142/usando-regex-em-php-para-capturar-qualquer-n%C3%BAmero-que-n%C3%A3o-esteja-dentro-de-aspas/352150?noredirect=1#comment706656_352150), é possível delimitar a string com aspas simples também, assim a `\` não precisa ser escrita como `\\`:

```
preg_match_all('/\'\d+\'|(\d+)/', $texto, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);
```

Veja [aqui](https://ideone.com/jb4Yph) um exemplo.

---

Este "truque" foi baseado [neste tutorial](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-best-trick.html#notarzan).

Comment: Realmente perfeito. Deu o resultado que eu esperava obter e sem o menor dos problemas. Aliás, excelente explicação de tudo envolvido. Vou ler mais a fundo os links externos agora para me aprofundar mais no assunto e melhorar minhas habilidades. Estou utilizando o  `preg_match_all("/\'\d+(?:\.\d+)?\'|(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)/", $texto, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);` Agradeço mais uma vez.

Comment: @DiegoBorges Dois sites que acho muito bons para aprender regex são [este](https://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html) e [este](https://www.rexegg.com) <- este último possui alguns tópicos bem avançados, inclusive, e é de onde tirei esta solução. E prepare-se para ler bastante, pois regex é um assunto sem fim! Quanto mais estudo, mais percebo que não sei nem a metade.. :-)

Comment: Só uma dica, quando for criar regex no PHP é mais fácil usar aspas simples, pois aspas simples não fazem o parse da barra invertida como um caractere especial. Ex.: `echo "0\t1";  // "0    1"` e `echo '0\t1";  // "0\t1'`

Comment: @fernandosavio Obrigado pela dica, faz tempo que não programo profissionalmente em PHP (só alguns scripts e respostas do Stack Overflow de vez em quando), então estou bem "enferrujado" nesta linguagem :-) Atualizei a resposta, obrigado!

Comment: Gostaria de estar na tua situação.. hahahaha

Comment: Deu uma excelente aula! Regexp é um tópico mt gostoso de praticar / discutir.

Answer (score 2):

Criei uma REGEX que acredito que atende a sua necessidade:

```
(?<=\s|^)(\d+[.,]{1}\d+|\d+)+(?=\s|$)
```

Faça um teste:

```
12,2 12.1021 14 '51' '1' '23323' 12
```

A única regra para ele funcione é que os números estejam separados por espaços.

**Explicações a lá @GuilhermeNascimento:**

```
(?<=\s|^)(\d+[.,]{1}\d+|\d+)+(?=\s|$)
  ^       ^            ^       ^
  .       .            .       ................ tem que ser o final da string ou ter espaços
  .       .            ............... pega apenas numeros
  .       .
  .       ................. pega numeros que possam ter (. ou ,) com numeros depois
  .
  ............... positive lookbehind (se houver espaçamento antes) ou é o inicio da string
```

Os número que serão resgatados são:

```
12,2 
12.1021 
14
12
```

Ficaria assim o código:

```
$string = "12,2 12.1021 14 '51' '1' '23323' 12";

preg_match_all("/(?<=\s|^)(\d+[.,]{1}\d+|\d+)+(?=\s|$)/", $string, $output_array);

print_r($output_array);
```

**[Veja o Funcionando](https://regexr.com/458gu)**